# Location Background Service

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I want to make tracking run when the application exits or runs on the background service does the plugin already support?
I have read this tutorial and I am still confused whether there are examples of projects [here](https://medium.com/flutter-io/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124) or is there a plugin for this?

Comment: Try [this](https://github.com/baseflowit/flutter-geolocator)

Comment: I see it does not support background services for Android ?

Comment: Currently that's the only packages which is closest to your needs. You can upvote on background issues there. And if you don't want to depend on that plugin,  you can implement it using `MethodChannel` or `EventChannel` on your own.